# Why does my Facebook Like button create a brand new Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-page

I'm trying to integrate Facebook into a site I'm developing, I have created a Facebook Page for the business & a Facebook app too - I am very confused with the documentation & terminology that Facebook uses.

I am using FBML to add a Recommend button to the footer of my site so that users can recommend that particular page but when I click on it, it creates a brand new Facebook page for that URI & seemingly ignores all the facebook & open graph metatag info.

FYI, these are the metatags that I'm using:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Page title"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="company"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysiteimage.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site Name"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="My_FB_Admin_ID"/>
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="My_FB_Page_ID" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="My_FB_App_ID" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Desctiption of page"/>
```

This is the FBML I'm using:

```
<fb:like width="940" action="recommend" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>
```

This is the Facebook Javascript SDK code I'm adding to each page before the `</body>` tag (it is only being added once per page):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'My_FB_App_ID', status: true, cookie: true,
        xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

Does anyone have any idea what the heck I should be doing? Should I be using an app as the fan page or the page I'm already using??

I would also really like to be able to 'Like/Recommend' the actual Facebook page from the site, is this possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Zander

Comment: So you have 3 places - site, fb app and fb page. Where do you put your like button - on your site? What do you want to like - site or fb app? What do you mean by it creates a brand new page? What kind of page is created and what is its url?

Comment: Yes, I have three places. I would like to 'Like' the facebook page, or at least have the 'Liked' links be associated with my Facebook page.

 - What do you mean by it creates a brand new page?
I mean that clicking a 'Like' button creates a new Facebook page specifically for that original site page. For example, if i have a page at www.site.com/contact, a new Facebook page is created for it with the name that appears in my site's page <title> tag. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue has to do with the `meta` property `og:type`. Anything other than `article` like a video/audio etc.  will create a new Facebook Page on the open social graph.

If you set `og:type` to `article`, or remove it altogether, the issue will go away.

I hope that helps.

Comment: You can add comments when you have 50 reputation. See the [faq].

Answer (score 0):

No mather where you place the "like" button you can specify the url on it, so in this wayonly one "page" is created ex:

```
your created html location = http://mywebsite.com
some other stuff

    <!-- like button -->

     <fb:like href="http://mywebsite.com" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="200" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>

    <!-- end like button -->


your other created html location = http://mywebsite.com/help

some other stuff

    <!-- like button -->

     <fb:like href="http://mywebsite.com" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="200" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>

    <!-- end like button -->
```

as you see here no mather what page your "like" button allways create the same page, even more you can specify your page aplication on it.

Remember even the "meta property" tags allways will create the same page if you specify the url and same content, if you left some part blank the facebook api will asume the current url and not will take any of the other parameters.Tha same apply to comments you can have the same comments box with the same comments on it if you specify the url.